# Static Html elements on different pages

Tags: theming

So, I have a frontpage where I simply have a big image and a button that leads to a second page. On that page I want this:

[image]

Which are two `sections`. However, when I'm on the `contact page` I don't want the `section Questions?`

I want to write this in `Html` as I don't see how I would create these sections in `Drupal`. So my question is how can I make sure it's not visible on the `contact page` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could do it - blocks, panels, template overrides.  The easiest way for you would probably to create a custom block and put the html in that.  Then you'd be able to set the block visibility to exclude the `/contact` page.

Comment: Is putting the html in a block a common way? It feels like cheating somehow

Comment: Not at all, that's exactly what they're for - make use of them whenever you can